# ContactEndpoint phone, Lync 2013

Tags: contacts, phone-number, endpoint, lync

my application that uses Lync 2013, communicates with a server via websocket, and receives notifications.
These notifications are in Json format, so I convert it to extract a string.
The string is a phone number, and I want to test if one of my contacts are the same phone number to display his name.

My If is always "false".
I wanted to use > and extract the value of DisplayName (phone number as string) but i didn't know how to do it.
This is my code.

```
foreach (var group in client.ContactManager.Groups)
                {
                    foreach (Contact contact in group)
                    {

                        List<object> endpoints = (List<object>)contact.GetContactInformation(ContactInformationType.ContactEndpoints);
                        List<object> phoneNumbers = endpoints.Cast<object>().Where<object>(N => ((ContactEndpoint)N).Type == ContactEndpointType.HomePhone ||
                                                               ((ContactEndpoint)N).Type == ContactEndpointType.MobilePhone ||
                                                               ((ContactEndpoint)N).Type == ContactEndpointType.WorkPhone ||
                                                               ((ContactEndpoint)N).Type == ContactEndpointType.OtherPhone).ToList();

                        if (phoneNumbers.ToList().Contains(call.caller))
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show(contact.GetContactInformation(ContactInformationType.DisplayName).ToString());
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Comment: I think that i f found the solution .                                                                       foreach(var phoneNumber in phoneNumbers)
       {
        if (((ContactEndpoint)phoneNumber).DisplayName.ToString() == "my phone number received")
        {
         MessageBox.Show(contact.GetContactInformation(ContactInformationType.DisplayName).ToString());
        }
       }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can ask the contact manager for a contact directly by the [number](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj274481.aspx) formatted as a tel URL.  e.g. "el:12345678"

e.g.

```
var contact = client.ContactManager.GetContactByUri("tel:" + call.caller);
```

Comment: Ooh, it's very easy and it works fine.                                                                 PS: I thought that the method "GetContactByUri" is used to search the contact but only by its uri (address), not by tel too. Thanks a lot

Comment: Please i have an other question about the number phone format. in my case the call.caller is always in this format '33123456789', but if the number's contact is in the format '+33123456789' or '0033123456789' so i can't find my contact. I have a dll that take a number in the first format and return a Json like this {"caller":"33172387760","callers":["+33123456789","0033123456789", ]}, but GetContactByUri take a string as argument. Do you have i idea how can i do it ?

Comment: Skype's native number format is E164, so it's actually preferred that you create a tel with a E164 number e.g. "tel:+123456789".  If you pass thorugh any other "number" it will try to convert it to E164 anyway which assumes you have setup dial plans correctly within the system.  So rule of thumb, use E164 number if you have it, else use the other number.

Comment: You can test what Skype does with the SfB natvie client and try to type in a numbers in the "Find someone or dial a number" search box and see what results you get out.

Comment: If you can handle multiple results, then you can use the contact search methods.  e.g. client.ContactManager.BeginSearch.  You may have to handle mutliple results though.  I would convert your system number to E164 format.  This requires local dial plan knowledge though.  If your phoen system can give you the numbers in E164, that would be preferred.

Comment: So if SfB use a native number format E164 : +12345, and my API returns the caller's number in 12345 format, i have just to add the '+' to my caller's number before passing it as argument in GetContactByUri methode. i work in SfB but i don't have a list contact, so i test with my own contact (client), and the project is for an entreprise that use SfB, so i think that all numbers are in E164 format.